# Is there a shorthand way to achieve this with CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm curious if there is a slightly faster way to achieve this.

Say for example I have the following CSS:

```
 #main_login input[type=text], #main_login input[type=password] {

 }
```

Is there a faster way? Sometimes I might have a line with many more declarations in it ie

```
 #main_login blah, #main_login meh, #main_login getting_long, #main_login super_long {

 }
```

Thats a lot of #main_login repeating. I've seen some advanced CSS'ers using asterix's and so forth and yet to explore that sort of thing. I imagine there's a better way to do what I'm doing.

Any pointers?

Comment: Excellent question, i'd like to know this too.

Comment: No. Not without using another syntax that compiles/generates down to plain css.

Comment: I use php to generate my css when it starts to get tedious and confusing to wade through.  Variables are especially nice.

Comment: "faster" is the wrong word here; this is as fast as it gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way I know of is to use something like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/):

```
#main_login {
    input[type=text] {
    }

    input[type=password] {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really, unless you use another technology like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

The asterix `*` is used to target any element, irrelevant of their tag - so if nothing but `<blah>`, `<meh>`, `<getting_long>` and `<super_long>` elements appear inside of `#main_login`, you could use something like...

```
#main_login * { /* property list */ }
```

The alternative could be to modify your HTML so all those elements share a class attribute, and then simply target that class... but then you're changing your HTML to cater to your CSS when it should be the other way around.

Comment: I'm going to cite my sources and admit that I've never used SASS but read about it on [@Jeff Atwood's blog in April 2010](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/whats-wrong-with-css.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could try using an asterisk:

```
#main_login *
{
  ....
}
```

But since there is a reason you don't just select all elements, you'll have to use CSS3's `:not()` selector to exclude certain elements:

```
#main_login *:not(.foo, .bar,, div.exclude_me)
{
  ....
}
```

You might have better luck just by creating a new class and applying it to those elements, since you can use multiple classes within CSS:

```
<div class="underlined big orange foobar">Foobar</div>
```

I do this sometimes with complicated stylesheets, as I can basically write in English to describe the styles pertaining to that element.

Comment: +1 for using `:not`... good idea! How's the browser support though?

Comment: It seems like no versions of IE (except for IE9) support it, but it works in almost every other browser. There are libraries which do add a lot of CSS3 selectors to IE: http://selectivizr.com/.

Comment: Thats great. I had no idea you could use exclusions.

Comment: `:not()` can be used without an asterisk, although the only difference is 1 character...

Comment: You're also better off writing in English to describe the meanings/purposes of elements, not styles :) I'll stop being annoying now.

Answer (score 1):

One great way to make your css more concise and readable is to use SCSS/SASS - http://sass-lang.com/. SCSS is a superset of CSS that allows you to define variables, create mixins, and nest definitions. It requires you to use a preprocessor to generate the final css, but there are plugins for many web frameworks available.

The above could be rewritten as:

```
#main_login {
  input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I love it. My stylesheets are so much more readable and maintainable now that I use SCSS.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what sub elements you are trying to match and if there is a CSS selector type that matches your use case.

The `*` can be used to match all elements, however it can be scoped:

```
#main_login * { }
```

This will match all elements under #main_login.  Or you can scope it to a particular element type:

```
#main_login div { }
```

This will match all divs under #main_login.

Here is the CSS2 reference for selectors:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching

CSS3 adds many new selectors but are not supported by older browsers:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Answer (score -1):

you can have a wrapper class or id

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="main_login">
...
</div>
</div>
```

so defining css for

```
.wrapper {
}
```

would be enough. Or just define css for

```
#main_login {
}
```

Comment: Because you're changing your HTML to cater to your CSS when it should be the other way around. Outside of a best-practice/personal-preference discussion, the question's not even tagged for HTML but is specifically about [selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) ;)

Comment: Also it doesn't actually solve the problem he was asking about.